# angularJS toggle button how to get ng-model value

Tags: angularjs

Can i know how to get value from toggle button in angularjs. I need to get value as Principle or contractor.

```
<div style="float: left; margin-top: 4px">Principal</div>
<div style="margin-left: 10px; float: left; margin-right: 10px"
   class="btn-switch"
   ng-class="{'btn-switch--on':toggle.switch}"
   ng-model="toggle.switch"
   ng-click="toggle.switch = !toggle.switch">
   <div class="btn-switch-circle"
      ng-class="{'btn-switch-circle--on':toggle.switch}"
      ng-model="toggle.switch"
      ng-click="!toggle.switch = toggle.switch"></div>
</div>
<div style="float: left; margin-top: 4px">Contractor</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

can you check like this..?

```
var result;
if(!toggle.switch){
result = 'Contractor'
}
else{
result = 'Principal'
}
```